# How can i get Current Progress of a video using Dailymotion iframe.?

Tags: html, iframe, html5-video, dailymotion-api

I want to get Current progress of a video played using  dailymotion iframe. I have tried multiple things but nothing has worked so far.

**I need to get this functnality implemented using  Dailymotion Iframe**

My current code looks like

```
<iframe id="myVideo" style="width:300px;height:300px;position:absolute;left:100px;top:0px;overflow:hidden"
frameborder="0" type="text/html" src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/player/{Player_id}.html?video=x84sh87&startTime=10"
allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" width="640" height="360"
width=" 100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay">
```

```
<script pe="text/javascript">
function getCurTime() {
  var x = document.querySelector("iframe");
  alert(x);}

</script><button type="button" onclick="getCurTime()">ClickMe</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use our Player API in order to get access to player data such as current `videoTime`.

It is required you embed the player using one of the dedicated SDKs.
You can see the list of available options here: [**Dailymotion Integration-methods**](https://developers.dailymotion.com/player/#Integration-methods)